# Writing multiple files using standard Unix I/O functions and appending MPI rank

Tags: c, file, io, mpi

The following function produces an error while running with any number of processes. Can someone kindly tell me why. I am using **MPICH 3.1**. (This is not an ideal approach but I am trying to understand the basics of **MPI I/O** - just saying that the example should work).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>

#define BUF 100

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int buf[BUF], rank, loop_i ;
FILE *fp ; 
char filename[BUF];  


MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

for(loop_i = 0 ; loop_i <= BUF - 1 ; loop_i++)
    buf[loop_i] = rank * BUF + loop_i ; 

sprintf(filename, "testfile.%d", rank);
fp = fopen(filename, "w");
fwrite(buf, sizeof(int), BUF, fp);
fclose(fp); 

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

**While compiling I get**:

```
mpiio_2.c: In function ‘main’:
mpiio_2.c:11: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
ld: warning: duplicate dylib /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
```

**While running with 4 procs**:

```
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 4584 RUNNING AT sepultrite7432.local
=   EXIT CODE: 224
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
```

Comment: You should better check for incorrect return values from `fopen` and `fclose` functions.

Comment: what's your question, acually? Your compiler tells you that the return type of `main()` is not `int` as it's supposed to be and the runtime tells you that `main()` is returning an unexpected value. Shouldn't be too difficult to combine this two informations into something meaningful...

Comment: It's weird but when I changed the return type to **int**, the code started running. [ I still cannot understand why as I have been running several codes with `void main()`].

Comment: [**the fact that it works doesn't mean that it's correct**, and in fact now it has exploded into your face. `int main()` is the *correct* way. `void main()` isn't correct - only MS allowed it. Don't know if they still allow hit thought]